# How to change the value of datepicker using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker, webdriverwait, dopostback

In a `table` element I have the following for a date picker:

```
<input name="tb_date" type="text" value="2020-07-15" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'tb_date\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="tb_date" class="align-center" style="font-size:14pt;width:120px;">
```

I can get the input element as follows:

```
date_element = driver.find_element_by_name('tb_date')
```

That is fine. But when I try to change the value on this element, it seems to **append** to the current value.

```
date_element.send_keys('2020-07-01')
date_element.click()
```

So the datepicker has a value of `'2020-07-152020-07-01'`

How can I delete the value attribute and input a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear and then sendkeys to that field.

```
date_element.clear();
date_element.send_keys('2020-07-01')
date_element.click();
```

Comment: Excellent answer. It works well.

Comment: Any idea how to control the input format for the date input when using different time zones regions on your OS

Comment: @Jordan could you pls explain more about your question with screenshot ? or ask new question and send url here

Answer (score 6):

Try using `.execute_script`:

```
date_element = driver.find_element_by_name('tb_date')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '2020-07-01';", date_element)
```